# Get bounds of rotated rectangle

Tags: math, svg, rotation, geometry, svg-transforms

I'm trying to get the `position` of the actual rotated rectangle inside the `bounding box`.

[image]

The rectangle is rotated by `120deg`

I'm trying to achieve the blue outline you can see here

[image]

I manage to get the `rotation` right using the `matrix` but I can't get the rest right.

Here is my code

```
let svg = document.querySelector('svg')
let overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay')
let rect = svg.children[0]

let bounds = rect.getBoundingClientRect()
let matrix = rect.getCTM()

overlay.style.top = bounds.top + 'px'
overlay.style.left = bounds.left + 'px'
overlay.style.width = bounds.width + 'px'
overlay.style.height = bounds.height + 'px'
overlay.style.transform = `matrix(${matrix.a},${matrix.b},${matrix.c},${matrix.d},0,0)`
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/wjugqn31/67/](http://jsfiddle.net/wjugqn31/65/)

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41898990  Is this information enough to calculate what you want?

Comment: In my case I don't know the height and with of the rectangle itself I only the bounding box width / height so I don't think it coul work in this case

Comment: So known data are  bounding box width / height AND rotation angle? No more?

Comment: Yes I know Boundingbox with height, width, top, left position and finally the angle (120deg). Nothing else

Comment: @MBo I have the exact inverse of this question, how to get the bounds of the unrotated rectangle https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54072295/how-to-get-correct-size-and-position-of-an-object-at-an-arbitrary-rotation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Known data: bounding box width `W`, height `H`, rotation angle `Fi`
Wanted: coordinates of rotated rectangle vertices.

Unknown source rectangle size: `w x h`

Bounding box size for this dimension and rotation angle:

[image]

```
 H = w * Abs(Sin(Fi)) + h * Abs(Cos(Fi))
 W = w * Abs(Cos(Fi)) + h * Abs(Sin(Fi))
 denote 
 as = Abs(Sin(Fi))
 cs = Abs(Cos(Fi))
```

so we can solve linear equation system and get (note singularity for `Pi/4` angle)

```
 h = (H * cs - W * as) / (cs^2 - as^2)
 w = -(H * as - W * cs) / (cs^2 - as^2)
```

Vertex coordinates:

```
 XatTopEdge = w * cs      (AE at the picture)
 YatRightEdge = h * cs    (DH)
 XatBottomEdge = h * as   (BG)
 YatLeftEdge = w * as     (AF)
```

Note that with given data we cannot differ between angles `Fi` and `90+Fi` but this fact perhaps does not influence on solution (`w` and `h` will exchange each other too)

Comment: implementation of [this](https://codepen.io/ravencolevol/pen/mdLZpMq)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could get the dimensions of the `rect` directly, and then apply the transform to it. In [summary](http://jsfiddle.net/wjugqn31/101/):

```
let rect = svg.children[0]
let matrix = rect.getScreenCTM()

overlay.style.top = '0'
overlay.style.left = '0'
overlay.style.width = `${rect.width.animVal.value}px`
overlay.style.height = `${rect.height.animVal.value}px`
overlay.style.transformOrigin = '0 0'
overlay.style.transform = `matrix(${matrix.a},${matrix.b},${matrix.c},${matrix.d},${matrix.e},${matrix.f})`
```

Comment: I really like this solution, it works really well on simple shapes but for some cases doesn't seems to work, you can see the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/wjugqn31/113/

Comment: @zaarr78 that's because the bounding box is tight, while the letter itself starts at coordinates ~ `11,31`. You can [fix that](http://jsfiddle.net/wjugqn31/142/) by adding an additional offset to the transform: `matrix(${matrix.a},${matrix.b},${matrix.c},${matrix.d},${matrix.e},${matrix.f}) translate(${bbox.x}px,${bbox.y}px)`