# Get bounds of unrotated rotated rectangle

Tags: javascript, canvas, ecmascript-6, transform, rectangles

I have a rectangle that has a rotation already applied to it. I want to get the the unrotated dimensions (the x, y, width, height).

Here is the dimensions of the element currently:

```
Bounds at a 90 rotation: {
 height     30
 width      0
 x          25
 y          10
}
```

Here are the dimensions after the rotation is set to none:

```
Bounds at rotation 0 {
 height     0
 width      30
 x          10
 y          25
}
```

In the past, I was able to set the rotation to 0 and then read the updated bounds . However, there is a bug in one of the functions I was using, so now I have to do it manually.

Is there a simple formula to get the bounds at rotation 0 using the info I already have?

*Update: The object is rotated around the center of the object.*

**UPDATE:**
What I need is something like the function below:

```
function getRectangleAtRotation(rect, rotation) {
    var rotatedRectangle = {}
    rotatedRectangle.x = Math.rotation(rect.x * rotation);
    rotatedRectangle.y = Math.rotation(rect.y * rotation);
    rotatedRectangle.width = Math.rotation(rect.width * rotation);
    rotatedRectangle.height = Math.rotation(rect.height * rotation);
    return rotatedRectangle;
}

var rectangle = {x: 25, y: 10, height: 30, width: 0 };
var rect2 = getRectangleAtRotation(rect, -90); // {x:10, y:25, height:0, width:30 }
```

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51462800/get-bounds-of-rotated-rectangle).

**UPDATE 2**
Here is the code I have. It attempts to get the center point of the line and then the x, y, width, and height:

```
var centerPoint = getCenterPoint(line);
var lineBounds = {};
var halfSize;

halfSize = Math.max(Math.abs(line.end.x-line.start.x)/2, Math.abs(line.end.y-line.start.y)/2);
lineBounds.x = centerPoint.x-halfSize;
lineBounds.y = centerPoint.y;
lineBounds.width = line.end.x;
lineBounds.height = line.end.y;

function getCenterPoint(node) {
    return {
        x: node.boundsInParent.x + node.boundsInParent.width/2,
        y: node.boundsInParent.y + node.boundsInParent.height/2
    }
}
```

I know the example I have uses a right angle and that you can swap the x and y with that but the rotation can be any amount.

**UPDATE 3**

I need a function that returns the unrotated bounds of a rectangle. I have the bounds at a specific rotation already.

```
function getUnrotatedRectangleBounds(rect, currentRotation) {
    // magic
    return unrotatedRectangleBounds;
}
```

Comment: When rotating on a canvas it's much easier to work with 1. The origin of your object, and 2. The angle of each point of your triangle (imagine if they were located on an imaginery circle). If you have that information, I can offer a formula that I've used quite often.

Comment: I have rotated rectangles and lines that I would like to unrotate. I can get the start x, start y, end x and end y of the rotated line and the bounds of that as mentioned? Would that help?

Comment: @kemicofa I can get you the center position of a line

Comment: Sure that would be nice. Also, you noticed that if you switch x,y and width,height it seems to fit your output?

Comment: In the example I'm using a right angle but it's not always a right angle. I'll put the code in the main post to get the center point of the line and the x and y (it might not be correct but seems to work so far)

Comment: Could you provide a non-degenerate case example.  All of your examples indicate a width or height of 0. This results in a line.

Answer (score 16):

I think I can handle the calculation of the bounds size without too much effort (few equations), I'm not sure, instead, how you would like `x` and `y` to be handled.

First, let's properly name things:

[image]

Now, we want to rotate it by some angle `alpha` (in radians):

[image]

To calculate the green sides, it is clear that it's made of two repeated rectangle-triangles as the following:

[image]

So, solving angles first, we know that:

1. the sum of the angles of a triangle is `PI`, or 180°;
2. the rotation is `alpha`;
3. one angle gamma is `PI / 2`, or 90°;
4. the last angle, beta, is `gamma - alpha`;

Now, knowing all the angles and a side, we can use the Law of Sines to calculate other sides.

As a brief recap, the Law of Sines tells us that there is an equality between the ratio of a side length and it's opposite angle. More info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines

In our case, for the upper left triangle (and the bottom right one), we have:

[image]

Remember that `AD` is our original height.

Given that the `sin(gamma)` is 1, and we also know the value of `AD`, we can write the equations:

[image]

[image]

For the upper right triangle (and the bottom left one), we then have:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Having all needed sides, we can easily calculate the width and height:

```
width = EA + AF
height = ED + FB
```

At this point we can write a quite easy method that, given a rectangle and a rotation angle in radians, can return new bounds:

```
function rotate(rectangle, alpha) {
  const { width: AB, height: AD } = rectangle
  const gamma = Math.PI / 4,
        beta = gamma - alpha,
        EA = AD * Math.sin(alpha),
        ED = AD * Math.sin(beta),
        FB = AB * Math.sin(alpha),
        AF = AB * Math.sin(beta)

  return {
    width: EA + AF,
    height: ED + FB
  }
}
```

This method can then be used like:

```
const rect = { width: 30, height: 50 }
const rotation = Math.PI / 4.2 // this is a random value it put here
const bounds = rotate(rect, rotation)
```

Hope there aren't typos...

Comment: This is very thorough but I'm not sure how to use it with what I have. If I have a rectangle at 10 x 10 and size 50 x 60 (or any values) and it is rotated 85 degrees, I want to rotate it -85 degrees the other direction and return a rectangle that has the new x, y, width and height. Is it possible to add x and y to the `rect`? I have the start size and end size in the main post. The rectangle is already rotated and I have all of the values from that. I want to unrotate it. The rect is rotated around the center if that helps.

Comment: Mhmm let me ask you a few question to clarify a bit more for me:
1. does your rectangle starts rotated? if yes, do you know how many degrees it is rotated?
2. x and y, in your coordinate system, are the one of the upper left corner (the A point) and not the bounds right?
3. the initial sizes you have are the outer bounds and you need the rectangle size after its unrotation?

Sorry for the repetition but english isn't my native language.

Comment: No problem. 1. Yes, it starts rotated it can be any value but in the example it is 90 degrees. 2. x and y are top and left positions. 0 x 0 is top left of document. less than 0 is off screen. 3. yes. outer bounds. the draw bounds or wherever a pixel is counts. x and y change as the rectangle is rotated. it is rotated and i need the size after it is unrotated back to zero rotation

Comment: @1.21gigawatts I am not sure that *any* rotated rectangle with all 90deg angles can be inscribed in another rectangle of given bounds. My other question for you is: do you know if this inner rectangle is skewed? I am working con a proof of concept at this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/713k230m56

Comment: It is not skewed @0xc14m1z

Comment: I have a rectangle rotated by an angle and I want to get the unrotated bounding box. I used your function but it's kind of not working. The EF is not defined and I tried to replace it by AF which defined but not used. but I get wrong results. I think it would be great if you created a jsfiddle or sandbox where we can play with it. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

I think I might get a solution but, for safety, I prefer to prior repeat what we have and what we need to be sure I understood everything correctly. As I said in a comment, english isn't my native language and I already wrote a wrong answer due to my lack of understanding of the problem :)

### What we have

[image: what we have]

We know that at `x` and `y` there is a bounds rectangle (green) of size `w` and `h` that contains another rectangle (the grey dotted one) rotated of `alpha` degrees.

We know that the y axis is flipped relatively to the Cartesian one, and that makes the angle to be considered clockwise instead of counter-clockwise.

### What we need

[image: what we need at first]

At first, we need to find the 4 vertices of the inner rectangle (`A`, `B`, `C` and `D`) and, knowing the position of the vertices, the size of the inner rectangle (`W` and `H`).

As a second step, we need to counter rotate the inner rectangle to 0 degrees, and find it's position `X` and `Y`.

[image: what we need at the end]

### Find the vertices

Generally speaking for each vertex we know only one coordinate, the x or the y. The other one "slides" along the side of the bounding box in relation to the angle alpha.

Let's start with `A`: we know `Ay`, we need `Ax`.

We know that the `Ax` lies between `x` and `x + w` in relation to the angle `alpha`.

When `alpha` is 0°, `Ax` is `x + 0`. When `alpha` is 90°, `Ax` is `x + w`. When alpha is 45°, `Ax` is `x + w / 2`.

Basically, `Ax` grows in relation of the sin(alpha), giving us:

[image: computing Ax]

Having `Ax`, we can easily compute `Cx`:

[image: computing Cx]

In the same way we can compute `By` and then `Dy`:

[image: computing By]

[image: computing Dy]

Writing some code:

```
// bounds is a POJO with shape: { x, y, w, h }, update if needed
// alpha is the rotation IN RADIANS
const vertices = (bounds, alpha) => {
  const { x, y, w, h } = bounds,
        A = { x: x + w * Math.sin(alpha), y },
        B = { x, y: y + h * Math.sin(alpha) },
        C = { x: x + w - w * Math.sin(alpha), y },
        D = { x, y: y + h - h * Math.sin(alpha) }
  return { A, B, C, D }
}
```

### Finding the sides

Now that we have all the vertices, we can easily compute the inner rectangle sides, we need to define a couple more points `E` and `F` for clarity of explanation:

[image: additional points]

Its clearly visible that we can use the Pitagorean Theorem to compute `W` and `H`  with:

[image: compute H]

[image: compute W]

where:

[image: compute EA]

[image: compute ED]

[image: compute AF]

[image: compute FB]

In code:

```
// bounds is a POJO with shape: { x, y, w, h }, update if needed
// vertices is a POJO with shape: { A, B, C, D }, as returned by the `vertices` method
const sides = (bounds, vertices) => {
  const { x, y, w, h } = bounds,
        { A, B, C, D } = vertices,
        EA = A.x - x,
        ED = D.y - y,
        AF = w - EA,
        FB = h - ED,
        H = Math.sqrt(EA * EA + ED * ED),
        W = Math.sqrt(AF * AF + FB * FB
  return { h: H, w: W }
}
```

### Finding the position of the counter-rotated inner rectangle

First of all, we have to find the angles (`beta` and `gamma`) of the diagonals of the inner rectangle.

[image: compute diagonals angles]

Let's zoom in a little bit and add some additional letters for more clarity:

[image: add some letters to compute beta]

We can use the Law of Sines to get the equations to compute `beta`:

[image: law of sines]

To make some calculations we have:

[image: compute GI]

[image: compute IC]

[image: delta]

[image: sin delta]

We need to compute `GC` first in order to have at least one side of the equation completely known. `GC` is the radius of the circumference the inner rectangle is inscribed in and also half of the inner rectangle diagonal.

Having the two sides of the inner rectangle, we can use the Pitagorean Theorem again:

[image: compute GC]

With `GC` we can solve the Law of Sines on `beta`:

[image: compute beta 1]

we know that `sin(delta)` is 1

[image: compute beta 2]

[image: compute beta 3]

[image: compute beta 4]

[image: compute beta 5]

Now, `beta` is the angle of the vertex `C` in relation with the unrotated x axis.

[image: C vertex angle is beta]

Looking again at this image, we can easily get the angles of all the other vertices:

[image: all vertices angles]

[image: D angle]

[image: A angle]

[image: B angle]

Now that we have almost everything, we can compute the new coordinates of the `A` vertex:

[image: compute A position]

[image: compute final A_x]

[image: compute final A_y]

From here, we need to translate both `Ax` and `Ay` because they are related to the center of the circumference, which is `x + w / 2` and `y + h / 2`:

[image: compute translated A_x]

[image: compute translated A_y]

So, writing the last piece of code:

```
// bounds is a POJO with shape: { x, y, w, h }, update if needed
// sides is a POJO with shape: { w, h }, as returned by the `sides` method
const origin = (bounds, sides) => {
  const { x, y, w, h } = bounds
  const { w: W, h: H } = sides
  const GC = r = Math.sqrt(W * W + H * H) / 2,
        IC = H / 2,
        beta = Math.asin(IC / GC),
        angleA = Math.PI + beta,
        Ax = x + w / 2 + r * Math.cos(angleA),
        Ay = y + h / 2 + r * Math.sin(angleA)
  return { x: Ax, y: Ay }
}
```

## Putting all together...

```
// bounds is a POJO with shape: { x, y, w, h }, update if needed
// rotations is... the rotation of the inner rectangle IN RADIANS
const unrotate = (bounds, rotation) => {
  const points = vertices(bounds, rotation),
        dimensions = sides(bounds, points)
  const { x, y } = origin(bounds, dimensions)
  return { ...dimensions, x, y }
}
```

I really hope this will solve your problem and that there are no typos. This was a very, veeeery funny way to spend my weekend :D

```js
// bounds is a POJO with shape: { x, y, w, h }, update if needed
// alpha is the rotation IN RADIANS
const vertices = (bounds, alpha) => {
 const { x, y, w, h } = bounds,
    A = { x: x + w * Math.sin(alpha), y },
    B = { x, y: y + h * Math.sin(alpha) },
    C = { x: x + w - w * Math.sin(alpha), y },
    D = { x, y: y + h - h * Math.sin(alpha) }
 return { A, B, C, D }
 }
  
// bounds is a POJO with shape: { x, y, w, h }, update if needed
// vertices is a POJO with shape: { A, B, C, D }, as returned by the `vertices` method
const sides = (bounds, vertices) => {
  const { x, y, w, h } = bounds,
      { A, B, C, D } = vertices,
      EA = A.x - x,
      ED = D.y - y,
      AF = w - EA,
      FB = h - ED,
      H = Math.sqrt(EA * EA + ED * ED),
      W = Math.sqrt(AF * AF + FB * FB)
  return { h: H, w: W }
}

// bounds is a POJO with shape: { x, y, w, h }, update if needed
// sides is a POJO with shape: { w, h }, as returned by the `sides` method
const originPoint = (bounds, sides) => {
  const { x, y, w, h } = bounds
  const { w: W, h: H } = sides
  const GC = Math.sqrt(W * W + H * H) / 2,
      r = Math.sqrt(W * W + H * H) / 2,
      IC = H / 2,
      beta = Math.asin(IC / GC),
      angleA = Math.PI + beta,
      Ax = x + w / 2 + r * Math.cos(angleA),
      Ay = y + h / 2 + r * Math.sin(angleA)
  return { x: Ax, y: Ay }
}
  
// bounds is a POJO with shape: { x, y, w, h }, update if needed
// rotations is... the rotation of the inner rectangle IN RADIANS
const unrotate = (bounds, rotation) => {
  const points = vertices(bounds, rotation)
  const dimensions = sides(bounds, points)
  const { x, y } = originPoint(bounds, dimensions)
  return { ...dimensions, x, y }
}

function shortNumber(value) {
  var places = 2;
 value = Math.round(value * Math.pow(10, places)) / Math.pow(10, places);
 return value;
}

function getInputtedBounds() {
  var rectangle = {};
  rectangle.x = parseFloat(app.xInput.value);
  rectangle.y = parseFloat(app.yInput.value);
  rectangle.w = parseFloat(app.widthInput.value);
  rectangle.h = parseFloat(app.heightInput.value);
  return rectangle;
}

function rotationSliderHandler() {
  var rotation = app.rotationSlider.value;
  app.rotationOutput.value = rotation;
  rotate(rotation);
}

function rotationInputHandler() {
  var rotation = app.rotationInput.value;
  app.rotationSlider.value = rotation;
  app.rotationOutput.value = rotation;
  rotate(rotation);
}

function unrotateButtonHandler() {
  var rotation = app.rotationInput.value;
  app.rotationSlider.value = 0;
  app.rotationOutput.value = 0;
  var outerBounds = getInputtedBounds();
  var radians = Math.PI / 180 * rotation;
  var unrotatedBounds = unrotate(outerBounds, radians);
  updateOutput(unrotatedBounds);
}

function rotate(value) {
  var outerBounds = getInputtedBounds();
  var radians = Math.PI / 180 * value;
  var bounds = unrotate(outerBounds, radians);
  updateOutput(bounds);
}

function updateOutput(bounds) {
  app.xOutput.value = shortNumber(bounds.x);
  app.yOutput.value = shortNumber(bounds.y);
  app.widthOutput.value = shortNumber(bounds.w);
  app.heightOutput.value = shortNumber(bounds.h);
}

function onload() {
  app.xInput = document.getElementById("x");
  app.yInput = document.getElementById("y");
  app.widthInput = document.getElementById("w");
  app.heightInput = document.getElementById("h");
  app.rotationInput = document.getElementById("r");
  
  app.xOutput = document.getElementById("x2");
  app.yOutput = document.getElementById("y2");
  app.widthOutput = document.getElementById("w2");
  app.heightOutput = document.getElementById("h2");
  app.rotationOutput = document.getElementById("r2");
  app.rotationSlider = document.getElementById("rotationSlider");
  app.unrotateButton = document.getElementById("unrotateButton");
  
  app.unrotateButton.addEventListener("click", unrotateButtonHandler);
  app.rotationSlider.addEventListener("input", rotationSliderHandler);
  app.rotationInput.addEventListener("change", rotationInputHandler);
  app.rotationInput.addEventListener("input", rotationInputHandler);
  app.rotationInput.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {if (e.keyCode==13) rotationInputHandler() });
  
  app.rotationSlider.value = app.rotationInput.value;
}

var app = {};
window.addEventListener("load", onload);
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  outline: 0px dashed red;
}

granola {
  display: flex;
  align-items: top;
}

flan {
  width: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
}

hamburger {
  display: flex:
  align-items: center;
}

spagetti {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}

fish {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 50px;
}

input[type=range] {
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 140px;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

button {
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom:1px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<granola>
  <fish>
    <spagetti>Bounds of Rectangle</spagetti><br><br>
    <flan>x: </flan><input id="x" type="text" value="14.39"><br>
    <flan>y: </flan><input id="y" type="text" value="14.39"><br>
    <flan>width: </flan><input id="w" type="text" value="21.2"><br>
    <flan>height: </flan><input id="h" type="text" value="21.2"><br>
    <flan>rotation:</flan><input id="r" type="text" value="90"><br>
    <button id="unrotateButton">Unrotate</button>    
  </fish>

  <fish>
    <spagetti>Computed Bounds</spagetti><br><br>
    <flan>x: </flan><input id="x2" type="text" disabled="true"><br>
    <flan>y: </flan><input id="y2" type="text"disabled="true"><br>
    <flan>width: </flan><input id="w2" type="text" disabled="true"><br>
    <flan>height: </flan><input id="h2" type="text" disabled="true"><br>
    <flan>rotation:</flan><input id="r2" type="text" disabled="true"><br>
    <input id="rotationSlider" type="range" min="-360" max="360" step="5"><br>
  </fish>
</granola>
```

Comment: @1.21gigawatts were you be able to try?

Comment: I did sortof. I put the code together but I'm not sure I'm doing it right. I've put the code into your answer as script example for you to test and edit if you so choose.

Comment: I am not able to edit the answer right now, don't know why. However, I think i figured out what the problem. The angle you are using is in degrees. Convert it in radians before giving it to the `unrotate` method with `Math.PI / 180 * [angle in degrees]`

Comment: It might not allow you to edit it since I'm editing the example code. I'll convert it to radians. Check back in 10 minutes

Comment: It's added. I used the functions you had in your post from yesterday. You'll want to review it obviously.

Comment: I see everything NaN. Did it work for you? When I tried your previous code earlier and with the radians conversion it seemed to work...

Comment: The form values were using strings instead of numbers. I added parseFloat to convert them to numbers. Try or try not. There is no do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186739/discussion-between-0xc14m1z-and-1-21-gigawatts).

Answer (score 5):

### How does this work?

*Calculation using width, height, x and y*

#### Radians and Angles

Using degrees calculate the radians and calculate the `sin` and `cos` angles:

```js
function calculateRadiansAndAngles(){
  const rotation = this.value;
  const dr = Math.PI / 180;
  const s = Math.sin(rotation * dr);
  const c = Math.cos(rotation * dr);
  console.log(rotation, s, c);
}

document.getElementById("range").oninput = calculateRadiansAndAngles;
```

```html
<input type="range" min="-360" max="360" id="range"/>
```

#### Generate 4 points

*we assume the origin of a rectangle is the center with the location of 0,0*

The double for loop will create the following value pairs for `i` and `j`: (-1,-1), (-1,1), (1,-1) and (1,1)

Using each pair, we can calculate one of the 4 square vectors.

*(i.e for (-1,1), `i = -1, j = 1`)*

```
const px = w*i/2; //-> 30 * -1/2 = -15
const py = h*j/2; //-> 50 * 1/2  = 25
//[-15,25]
```

Once we have a point, we can calculate the new position of that point by including the rotation.

```
const nx = (px*c) - (py*s);
const ny = (px*s) + (py*c);
```

### Solution

Once all the points are calculated based off of the rotation, we can redraw our square.

Before the draw call, a `translate` is used to position the cursor at the `x` and `y` of the rectangle. This is the reason as to why I was able to assume the center and the origin of the rectangle was `0,0` for the calculations.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const range = document.getElementById("range");
const rotat = document.getElementById("rotat");

range.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  rotat.innerText = this.value;
  handleRotation(this.value);
})

const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
const container = document.getElementById("container");

const rect = {
  x: 50,
  y: 75,
  w: 30,
  h: 50
}

function handleRotation(rotation) {
  const { w, h, x, y } = rect;
  
  const dr = Math.PI / 180;
  const s = Math.sin(rotation * dr);
  const c = Math.cos(rotation * dr);
  
  const points = [];
  for(let i = -1; i < 2; i+=2){
    for(let j = -1; j < 2; j+=2){
      
      const px = w*i/2;
      const py = h*j/2;
      
      const nx = (px*c) - (py*s);
      const ny = (px*s) + (py*c);
      points.push([nx, ny]);
    }
  }
  //console.log(points);
  draw(points);
  
}

function draw(points) {
  context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.save();
  context.translate(rect.x+(rect.w/2), rect.y + (rect.h/2))
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(...points.shift());
  [...points.splice(0,1), ...points.reverse()]
  .forEach(p=>{
    context.lineTo(...p);
  })
  context.fill();
  context.restore();
}

window.onload = () => handleRotation(0);
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

div>p {
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

div>input {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="rotat">0</p>
  <input type="range" id="range" min="-360" max="360" value="0" step="5" />
</div>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: The example is neat but how do I apply it to my question?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts , ah I might have taken it too far. The bounds you refer to are what exactly? x, y, width, height at a specific angle? Could you provide me the expected output of a rectangle rotated at a 45 degree angle? Thanks.

Comment: The untransformed bounds are `x: 10, y: 25, w: 30, h: 0` (height can be 1). The bounds at a 45 degree angle are `x: 14.39, y: 14.39, w: 21.2, h: 21.2`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the basic code for a rectangle rotating(Unrotating is the same thing only with a negative angle) around its center.

```
function getUnrotatedRectangleBounds(rect, currentRotation) {

    //Convert deg to radians
    var rot = currentRotation / 180 * Math.PI;
    var hyp = Math.sqrt(rect.width * rect.width + rect.height * rect.height);
    return {
       x: rect.x + rect.width / 2 - hyp * Math.abs(Math.cos(rot)) / 2,
       y: rect.y + rect.height / 2 - hyp * Math.abs(Math.sin(rot)) / 2,
       width: hyp * Math.abs(Math.cos(rot)),
       height: hyp * Math.abs(Math.sin(rot))
       } 
}
```

The vector starting at the origin(0,0) and ending at (width,height) is projected onto a unit vector for the target angle (cos rot,sin rot) * hyp.

The absolute values guarantee the width and height are both positive.

The coordinates of the projection are the width and height, respectively, of the new rectangle.

For the x and y values, take the original values at the center(x + rect.x) and move it back out(- 1/2 * NewWidth) so it centers the new rectangle.

Example

```js
function getUnrotatedRectangleBounds(rect, currentRotation) {
    //Convert deg to radians
    var rot = currentRotation / 180 * Math.PI;
    var hyp = Math.sqrt(rect.width * rect.width + rect.height * rect.height);
    return {
       x: rect.x + rect.width / 2 - hyp * Math.abs(Math.cos(rot)) / 2,
       y: rect.y + rect.height / 2 - hyp * Math.abs(Math.sin(rot)) / 2,
       width: hyp * Math.abs(Math.cos(rot)),
       height: hyp * Math.abs(Math.sin(rot))
    }
}

var originalRectangle = {x:10, y:25, width:30, height:0};
var rotatedRectangle = {x:14.39, y:14.39, width:21.2, height:21.2};
var rotation = 45;
var unrotatedRectangle = getUnrotatedRectangleBounds(rotatedRectangle, rotation);

var boundsLabel = document.getElementById("boundsLabel");
boundsLabel.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(unrotatedRectangle);
```

```html
<span id="boundsLabel"></span>
```

Comment: I added a code snippet example. The registration point is from the center of the rectangle.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts, Is the originalRectangle supposed to come from the rotatedRectangle in your example snippet?  If so, this is not a rotation of the original.  It violates the triangle inequality, unless a translation occurs before rotation (there would not be enough information in the rectangle and angle to solve). I don't understand what you mean by registration point in this context.  The both of the rectangles(input and solution) in my answer are defined by the top left corner as the origin of the rectangle.  It is rotated around the center point(the pivot).

Comment: By registration point I mean the center point. If the rectangle was 100 x 100 the registration point would be 50 x 50. I have design software that gives the bounds of the rectangle. The top left of the document is 0 x 0. The original rectangle is offset from that where 10 x 10 is moved down and to the right by 10. It should be cartesian coordinates system unless that information changes it.

Comment: I think my question must be reposted because it is apparent now that this information fundamentally changes the answer. I say this because the coordinate system of the document starts from 0x0, the rotation of the object is from the center and not the upper left corner and the rotation is in degrees and not radians.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts,  The degrees versus radians is irrelevant. It is already handled in the code(the rot variable), as well a the origin at 0,0)  It is the bounds that is giving the confusion.  Is the rotatedbounds calulated with its size as distance from the origin?