# How to get height and width of element when it is rotated

Tags: javascript, html, css

As I can get position of element from left side of screen using `e.getBoundingClientRect().left`

When we want to get the position of end points then add width or height according to need but how to get the position of end points when element is rotated.

Is it possible to get values

[image]

```js
let getBoxPos = document.querySelectorAll(".demo")
let box1 = document.querySelector("#box1")
let box2 = document.querySelector("#box2")
let box3 = document.querySelector("#box3")
let s = "";


function func() {
  getBoxPos.forEach(e => {
    let figXValue = e.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    s = Number(s) + Number(1);
    console.log("Start distance for box" + s + ":" + figXValue)
  })
  console.log("End distance for box1:" + (box1.getBoundingClientRect().left + 24));
  console.log("End distance for box3:" + (box3.getBoundingClientRect().left + 104));
  console.log("Don't know the correct way for box2:Is it box2.getBoundingClientRect().left + 100 or box2.getBoundingClientRect().left + 20 or none of them ");
}
func();
```

```css
.demo {
  height: 100px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.demo:nth-child(2) {
  border: 2px solid red;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.demo:nth-child(3) {
  border: 2px solid green;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="demo" id="box1"></div>
<div class="demo" id="box2"></div>
<div class="demo" id="box3"></div>
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/51463527/17175441

Comment: Do yu know if it has been rotated about the central point or might it be elsewhere?

Comment: @AHaworth I used the `transform-origin: top center;` so it is from the center top part but the values remains same. If you can provide any different or better solution I will be really thankful

Answer (score 1):

**What we know:** `Height`, `width` of element and the angle `θ` because elements has animation or element is transformed(rotated)

**What we don't know or need to find:** New `width` and `height` of element after rotation

> If we know a angle & a side(height, width in this case) of right angle triangle than we can find other sides too.

To solve a triangle with one side, you also need one of the non-right angled angles. If not, it is impossible:

1. If you have the hypotenuse, multiply it by sin(θ) to get the length
   of the side opposite to the angle.
2. Alternatively, multiply the hypotenuse by cos(θ) to get the side
   adjacent to the angle.
3. If you have the non-hypotenuse side adjacent to the angle, divide it
   by cos(θ) to get the length of the hypotenuse.
4. Alternatively, multiply this length by tan(θ) to get the length of
   the side opposite to the angle.
5. If you have an angle and the side opposite to it, you can divide the
   side length by sin(θ) to get the hypotenuse.
6. Alternatively, divide the length by tan(θ) to get the length of the
   side adjacent to the angle.

[Taken from OMNI Calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/right-triangle-side-angle)

[image]

Only single angle is given but other are found using angle formulas and relations.

Now as the question asks: How to get position of blue point than we have to add this to `left` value

```
Height*Sinθ + Width*Cosθ
```

---

The final code becomes:

```
box2.getBoundingClientRect().left + Height*Sinθ + Width*Cosθ
```

> You must include border too if any in height and width, if wanted from border edge

> As [A Haworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10867454/a-haworth) pointed out rotation can be from any point, so checked the compatibility for different positions and it seems compatible with rotation from any point so far. [image] [image] >>The element is rotated at an angle from anywhere.

[This answer may help further](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54112751/16846346)

Comment: What is the transform-origin in the above?

Comment: It is `transform-origin: top center;` @AHaworth

Comment: @AHaworth updated the answer to cope with problem you pointed. Can you plz tell that this is right or wrong way to do this or suggest any method