# Why the value of end point of element is wrong when using a function

Tags: javascript, html, css

> The problem is solved when adding angles individually and then using `ttheta`(without calling a function to add angles and than using `ttheta`), but can anyone tell about why using function here is wrong or what problem is this function causing

The issue is solved by using this:

```
    dtransform = window.getComputedStyle(leg1, null).getPropertyValue("transform");
    values = dtransform.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
    dtheta = Math.round(Math.atan2(values[1], values[0]) * (180 / Math.PI));
    dtransform1 = window.getComputedStyle(leg2, null).getPropertyValue("transform");
    values1 = dtransform1.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
    dtheta1 = Math.round(Math.atan2(values1[1], values1[0]) * (180 / Math.PI));

    ttheta = dtheta + dtheta1;
```

Instead of using function.

What I am trying to achieve is to get value of end points of an element when it is rotated from left and top of browser.

[image]

> X & Y values are max-distance of end points of shoe

I get right values at some points and wrong at some. I tried to add angle from the parent element but that also don't solve the problem.

[This is the related answer from which I had taken help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69966021/16846346)

> To check values are right or wrong I added an event to get `clientX` of mouse click. And values of element positions are taken when **Try** button is clicked.

Am I doing something wrong, any insights will be really helpful

```js
let leg1 = document.querySelector(".Leg1Shoe")
let leg2 = document.querySelector(".Leg1Part")
let animeAll = document.querySelectorAll(".allClass")
let animePause = false

let ttheta = 0;

function getPos() {
  if (!animePause) {
    animeAll.forEach(e => {
      e.classList.add("AnimatePaused");
    })
    animePause = true;
  } else {
    animeAll.forEach(e => {
      e.classList.remove("AnimatePaused");
    })
    animePause = false;
  }

  let h, w, x, dx, tx, y, dy, ty = "";
  leg1.style.outline = "1px solid red"
  h = leg1.offsetHeight;
  w = leg1.offsetWidth;
  x = leg1.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  y = leg1.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  func2(leg2);
  func2(leg1);
  dx = (Number(h * (Math.sin(ttheta * (Math.PI / 180)))) + Number(w * (Math.cos(ttheta * (Math.PI / 180))))).toFixed(2);
  dy = (Number(w * (Math.sin(ttheta * (Math.PI / 180)))) + Number(h * (Math.cos(ttheta * (Math.PI / 180))))).toFixed(2);
  tx = (Number(x) + Number(Math.abs(dx))).toFixed(2);
  ty = (Number(y) + Number(Math.abs(dy))).toFixed(2);
  console.log("X:" + tx, "Y:" + ty);
}

function func2(e) {
  let dtransform, dtheta, values = "";
  dtransform = window.getComputedStyle(e, null).getPropertyValue("transform");
  if (dtransform != "none") {
    values = dtransform.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
    dtheta = Math.round(Math.atan2(values[1], values[0]) * (180 / Math.PI));
  } else {
    dtheta = 0;
  };
  ttheta = Number(ttheta) + Number(dtheta);
}

leg1.addEventListener('click', mousePos);

function mousePos(e) {
  console.log("X:" + e.clientX, "Y:" + e.clientY)
}
```

```css
.Leg1Part {
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  top: 43px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: green;
  transform-origin: top center;
  animation: animateLeg1Part 5.0s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes animateLeg1Part {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(40deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(25deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(30deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(60deg);
  }
}

.Leg1Shoe {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 73px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  transform-origin: center left;
  animation: animateLeg1Shoe 5.0s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes animateLeg1Shoe {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(15deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(30deg);
  }
}

.AnimatePaused {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div class="Leg1Part allClass">
  <div class="Leg1Shoe allClass"></div>
</div>
<button onclick="getPos()">Try</button>
```

**Thanks for help in advance**

Comment: The main problem is when the element get from center to the left side and can be seen easily. If the difference is about 4-5px than it's ok but it is sometimes 10-25px or more

Comment: Are you trying just to make the "shoe" and the "leg" to rotate as one?

Comment: Yes shoe is attached to leg and when leg rotates, shoe also rotates . But shoe also has a different animation @tromgy

Comment: Does the "shoe" need to "articulate" or should it stay at 90 degrees to the "leg" while the leg rotates?

Comment: @tromgy needs to be rotated like a effect of moving so added a animation in it

Comment: Then you need to calculate the combined transformation matrix for the shoe, and then apply this matrix to each point on the shoe that you want to get the coordinates of. The combined transformation is the matrix product of the leg transform and shoe transform matrices.

Comment: Thanks @tromgy but can you tell how to find combined transformation or multiply matrices gotten from `transform` property

Answer (score 1):

This is not a simple answer that can give you a complete solution, but just an outline of the process you can follow.

1. You get the transformation matrices for the "leg" and the "shoe", as you already do, by calling `getPropertyValue("transform")` This gives you a string like this: `matrix(-0.568718, 0.822533, -0.822533, -0.568718, 0, 0)`, this is a *shortened* form of a 3x3 transformation matrix:

```
| cos(theta) -sin(theta) 0 |
| sin(theta) cos(theta)  0 |
| 0          0           1 |
```

2. Parse the string and create a 2d array for this matrix. Note: since you don't have any translation (two zeros in the last column) you can operate on 2x2 matrices.
3. Multiple the transformation matrices for the "leg" and the "shoe". It's a tedious process, and you can use the [mathjs](https://mathjs.org) library to help.
4. Multiply the resulting transformation matrix by the vector of each point's original coordinates. This will give you the coordinates of the point with all rotations applied.

Here are some references:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/matrix()
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation
- [http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~shen.94/681/Site/Slides_files/transformation_review.pdf](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/%7Eshen.94/681/Site/Slides_files/transformation_review.pdf)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm

Comment: Thanks a lot tromgy for the solution(+1). The problem is also solved when manually adding 
 values instead the use of function to add values. Can you tell about that too.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "adding values".

Comment: I have added the code which works in question and found a sideways. Thanks for your time tromgy.