# Can rectangle be placed inside other rectangle?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, rectangles, bounding-box

I was given width and height of two rectangles and have to determine if the first one has enough space to be inside the second one.

I checked the obvious horizontal and vertical cases, but what about **rotation**?

Can someone give me a little hint?

Comment: Are you given an angle for each of them, or are you checking that the second one fits into the first whatever its angle?

Comment: @CorentinPane There is no information about angles. I assume the task implies that it is possible to rotate them in any manner

Comment: So are you looking to determine if there *exists* a rotation angle that allows one to fit in the other, or if it is possible to fit one into the other *for all* rotation angles?

Comment: @CorentinPane I'm looking to determine if the rotations make sense if neither of previous two conditions are satisfied: 1) bottom left position 2) the case when we rotate it by 90 degrees

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate dimensions of bounding box for rotated rectangle depending on rotation angle as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51462800/get-bounds-of-rotated-rectangle/51463527#51463527)

```
H = w * Abs(Sin(Fi)) + h * Abs(Cos(Fi))
W = w * Abs(Cos(Fi)) + h * Abs(Sin(Fi))
```

where `w, h` are rotated rectangle dimensions and `H, W` are bounding box dimensions.

There might exist some intervals of angles where `H<Height2` and some intervals with `W<Width2`. If these intervals do intersect, so rotated rectangle fits into the second one.