# Crop/zoom formula after rotating an image

Tags: math, geometry, formula

Any idea on the formula if I rotate a 16:9 image to then Crop/Zoom in so the entire 16:9 screen is filled?

For example, when I angle my image by 4degrees, I have to zoom in my editing program which starts from 1.0 to 1.121
Here are 3 example

- 4 = 1.121
- 45 = 1.963
- 90 = 1.777

The value goes higher for a 45-degree angle, so the graph is almost kinda sorta a Bell curve on a graph (not quite).

```
to put it another way, just like photoshop, if you rotate an image a little, how much do you have to zoom in to fill the boundaries again so there is no white space on the edges.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have initial rectangle with height `h` and width `w=16/9*h`, then after rotation bounding rectangle has dimensions ([here with picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51462800/get-bounds-of-rotated-rectangle/51463527#51463527)):

```
H = 16/9 * h * Abs(Sin(Fi)) + h * Abs(Cos(Fi))
W = 16/9 * h * Abs(Cos(Fi)) + h * Abs(Sin(Fi))
```

Now needed coefficients by vertical and by horizontal axes:

```
cfvert = (16/9 * h * Abs(Sin(Fi)) + h * Abs(Cos(Fi))) / h = 
        16/9 * Abs(Sin(Fi)) + Abs(Cos(Fi))

cfhor =  (16/9 * h * Abs(Cos(Fi)) + h * Abs(Sin(Fi))) / (16/9 * h) = 
        Abs(Cos(Fi)) + 9/16 * Abs(Sin(Fi))
```

and result is maximum from these coefficients - definitely the first one:

```
coeff = max(cfvert, cfhor)  = 16/9 * Abs(Sin(Fi)) + Abs(Cos(Fi))
```

Comment: implemention of [this](https://codepen.io/ravencolevol/pen/mdLZpMq)