How do I calculate the size of the zero matrix needed to display the entire rotated image?
I am trying to write a python program that applies a selected 'image processing' operation to the loaded image without using the ready-made functions in the cv2 library. Below is the image rotation function:
# * Python version:  3.10.11 (tags/v3.10.11:7d4cc5a, Apr  5 2023, 00:38:17) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
# * OpenCV version:  4.9.0
# * Numpy version:   1.26.4
# * PyQt5 version:   5.15.10

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTextEdit, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QComboBox, QLabel, QFileDialog, QInputDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage, QColor
import cv2
import numpy as np

red_color = QColor(204, 0, 0)
green_color = QColor(0, 153, 0)
blue_color = QColor(0, 102, 255)
black_color = QColor(0, 0, 0)

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.image = None

    def initUI(self):
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.terminal_codes = QTextEdit(self)
        self.terminal_codes.setReadOnly(True)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.terminal_codes)
        self.terminal_codes.setFixedSize(400,150)
        
        self.upload_button = QPushButton('Upload Image', self)
        self.upload_button.clicked.connect(self.upload_image)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.upload_button)

        self.operation_combo = QComboBox(self)
        self.operation_combo.addItem('Select Operation')
        self.operation_combo.addItem('Image Rotation')
        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.operation_combo)

        self.apply_button = QPushButton('Apply and Download', self)
        self.apply_button.clicked.connect(self.apply_operation)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.apply_button)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.show()
        self.terminal_codes.setTextColor(green_color)
        self.terminal_codes.append("Program is ready.")
        
        self.operation_combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.update_terminal_codes)
        
    def update_terminal_codes(self, index):
        # Update terminal codes function
            
    def upload_image(self):
        # Upload image function
    
    def apply_operation(self):
        
        operation = self.operation_combo.currentText()

        if operation == 'Image Rotation':
            angle, ok = QInputDialog.getDouble(self, 'Image Rotation', 'Enter angle:')
            if ok:
                rotated_image = self.rotate_image(self.image, angle)
                self.download_image(rotated_image)
                self.terminal_codes.clear()
                self.terminal_codes.setTextColor(green_color)
                self.terminal_codes.append("Rotation angle:{}\nImage Rotation operation was applied.".format(angle))
    
    def download_image(self, image):
        # Download image function

    def rotate_image(self, image, angle):
        (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
        center = (w // 2, h // 2)
        rotated = np.zeros((h, w, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
        for i in range(h):
            for j in range(w):
                new_x = (j - center[0]) * np.cos(np.deg2rad(angle)) + (i - center[1]) * np.sin(np.deg2rad(angle)) + center[0]
                new_y = -(j - center[0]) * np.sin(np.deg2rad(angle)) + (i - center[1]) * np.cos(np.deg2rad(angle)) + center[1]
                if new_x >= 0 and new_x < h and new_y >= 0 and new_y < w:
                    x0 = int(np.floor(new_x))
                    y0 = int(np.floor(new_y))
                    x1 = int(np.ceil(new_x))
                    y1 = int(np.ceil(new_y))
                    if x0 < 0:
                        x0 = 0
                    if y0 < 0:
                        y0 = 0
                    if x1 >= w:
                        x1 = w - 1
                    if y1 >= h:
                        y1 = h - 1
                    a = new_x - x0
                    b = new_y - y0
                    c = 1 - a
                    d = 1 - b
                    for channel in range(3):
                        rotated[i, j, channel] = (c * d * image[y0, x0, channel] + a * d * image[y0, x1, channel] + c * b * image[y1, x0, channel] + a * b * image[y1, x1, channel])
        return rotated

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

The rotate_image function works like this:

With h, w, and center we calculate the height, width and center of the image.
With rotated = np.zeros((h, w, 3), dtype=np.uint8) we create an empty matrix to place the result image.
With new_x and new_y inside the nested (i, j) for loops, we calculate the new position of each pixel after the rotation.
With the query new_x >= 0 and new_x < h and new_y >= 0 and new_y < w we check if the new pixel position is within the image boundaries. If not, we ignore the pixel. If the condition is met, we do the remaining operations. I dictated the remaining operations to the AI because I didn't know how to do it. Here is the explanation of the AI: "This part of the function performs bilinear interpolation to calculate the new pixel values. It finds the four nearest pixels to the new position, and calculates the new pixel value as a weighted average of these four pixels."
Finally we return the rotated image.

My problem is that I can't show the entire returned image because the query new_x >= 0 and new_x < h and new_y >= 0 and new_y < w ignores pixels outside the boundary.Result image:
enter image description here
I think I need to rewrite the code rotated = np.zeros((h, w, 3), dtype=np.uint8) to solve this problem. But I don't know how to mathematically express a matrix in which the rotated image fits. I mean:
enter image description here
In the image above, the black border represents the space the image needs to fit after rotation.
Since my math knowledge is not enough, I don't know how to calculate a zero matrix where this image can fit using the rotation angle, height, width of the image (the bounding box of a rotated image). I need help with this.

Rotate the coordinates of the four corners, then take the min/max x and min/max y.

I would use pillow to rotate image - it will no need to calculate size of matrix. image.rotate(angle, expand=True). Doc: Image.rotate

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51463527/844416

Here's something that works.
code00.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

import cv2
import numpy as np


# @TODO - cfati: Method from question
def rotate_image(image, angle):
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    center = (w // 2, h // 2)
    rotated = np.zeros((h, w, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):
            new_x = (j - center[0]) * np.cos(np.deg2rad(angle)) + (i - center[1]) * np.sin(np.deg2rad(angle)) + center[0]
            new_y = -(j - center[0]) * np.sin(np.deg2rad(angle)) + (i - center[1]) * np.cos(np.deg2rad(angle)) + center[1]
            if new_x >= 0 and new_x < h and new_y >= 0 and new_y < w:
                x0 = int(np.floor(new_x))
                y0 = int(np.floor(new_y))
                x1 = int(np.ceil(new_x))
                y1 = int(np.ceil(new_y))
                if x0 < 0:
                    x0 = 0
                if y0 < 0:
                    y0 = 0
                if x1 >= w:
                    x1 = w - 1
                if y1 >= h:
                    y1 = h - 1
                a = new_x - x0
                b = new_y - y0
                c = 1 - a
                d = 1 - b
                for channel in range(3):
                    rotated[i, j, channel] = (c * d * image[y0, x0, channel] + a * d * image[y0, x1, channel] + c * b * image[y1, x0, channel] + a * b * image[y1, x1, channel])
    return rotated


def rotate_point(x, y, xc, yc, cos_, sin_):
    return (x - xc) * cos_ - (y - yc) * sin_, (y - yc) * cos_ + (x - xc) * sin_


def rotate(img, alpha, original_size=False):
    h0, w0 = img.shape[:2]
    xc0 = w0 / 2
    yc0 = h0 / 2
    if original_size:
        w1, h1 = w0, h0
        xc1, yc1 = xc0, yc0
    else:
        cos = np.cos(np.deg2rad(alpha))
        sin = np.sin(np.deg2rad(alpha))
        xtl, ytl = rotate_point(0, 0, xc0, yc0, cos, sin)
        xtr, ytr = rotate_point(w0, 0, xc0, yc0, cos, sin)
        xbl, ybl = rotate_point(0, h0, xc0, yc0, cos, sin)
        xbr, ybr = rotate_point(w0, h0, xc0, yc0, cos, sin)

        xs = (xtl, xtr, xbl, xbr)
        ys = (ytl, ytr, ybl, ybr)

        w1, h1 = round(max(xs) - min(xs)), round(max(ys) - min(ys))
        xc1, yc1 = w1 / 2, h1 / 2

    cosr = np.cos(np.deg2rad(-alpha))
    sinr = np.sin(np.deg2rad(-alpha))

    ret = np.zeros((h1, w1, img.shape[2]), dtype=img.dtype)
    for y1 in range(h1):
        for x1 in range(w1):
            x0, y0 = rotate_point(x1, y1, xc1, yc1, cosr, sinr)
            x0 = round(x0 + xc0)
            y0 = round(y0 + yc0)
            if 0 <= x0 < w0 and 0 <= y0 < h0:
                ret[y1, x1] = img[y0, x0]
    return ret


def main(*argv):
    orig = cv2.imread("img.png")
    angle = int(input("Enter angle (degrees): "))
    cv2.imshow(f"Original: {orig.shape[1]}x{orig.shape[0]}", orig)
    # Original function raises IndexError
    #rot0 = rotate_image(orig, angle)
    #cv2.imshow(f"Rotated question ({angle}): {rot0.shape[1]}x{rot0.shape[0]}", rot0)
    rot1 = rotate(orig, angle, original_size=True)
    cv2.imshow(f"Rotated ({angle}, same size): {rot1.shape[1]}x{rot1.shape[0]}", rot1)
    rot2 = rotate(orig, angle, original_size=False)
    cv2.imshow(f"Rotated ({angle}, enlarged): {rot2.shape[1]}x{rot2.shape[0]}", rot2)
    print("Press a key on any drawing window to exit...")
    cv2.waitKey(delay=0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(
        "Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(
            " ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
            64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32,
            sys.platform,
        )
    )
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)

Notes:

As also specified in the code, the rotating function from the question doesn't work (at least for this image)

The implementation only uses simple transformations (there's nothing smart about it)

On the performance side, I only "cached" the trigonometrical function results (to avoid computing them for every point). There are improvements that can be done:

Get rid of rotate_point ("inline" its code)

Use (faster) NumPy routines




Output:

Might also be interesting going over: [SO]: How to generate squares (randomly located, equally sized, randomly rotated) that don't intersect each other? (@CristiFati's answer).

I have tried both your code and the imutils.rotate_bound method. Each time the program closes by itself without generating any error or image. I have no idea what is going on. Is it a problem with my hardware? rtx 3050ti mobile, intel i7H

I'm not sure what the problem is, if everything is setup correctly it should run fine. However you could take the function and integrate it into your existing code which works. However due to results experimented with your function, I'm not sure what is correct in the question and what isn't.
