# Konva JS get new point positions for line after dragging or scaling

Tags: reactjs, canvas, konvajs, react-konva

I have a closed `Line` shape in Konva, and I need to get the new positions for its points after the object has been dragged.  I've tried using the `getAbsoluteTransform().point()` method [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59098408/konva-get-corners-coordinate-of-a-rotated-rectangle/65645262#65645262), but the points it returns seem to be incorrect; if I apply the new points to the shape, it moves the line more than expected, and in some cases will scale it, even if I didn't scale it in any way.

Is there something I'm missing, or do I need to use some other method to determine the new points for the `Line`?

```js
export const Polygon = ({ obj, listening, selected, onClick, onDragEnd, onDragStart }: Props) => {
    const shape = useRef<Konva.Line>(null);
    const transformer = useRef<Konva.Transformer>(null);

    // instantiate and hide the transformer
    useEffect(() => {
      transformer.current?.nodes([shape.current!]);
      transformer.current?.hide();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (selected) {
        transformer.current?.show();
        transformer.current?.getLayer()?.batchDraw();
      } else {
        transformer.current?.hide();
      }
    }, [selected]);

    const handleDragEnd = () => {
      const next = obj.points.map((coords) => {
        const { x, y } = shape.current!.getAbsoluteTransform().point({
          x: coords[0],
          y: coords[1]
        });
        return [x, y];
      });
      
      // persists the shape to a database; does not do any additional transformations to the points
      onDragEnd(obj.id, [next]);
    };

    return (
      <>
        <Line
          id={obj.id}
          fill={rgba(obj.color, 0.25)}
          stroke={obj.color}
          strokeWidth={2}
          strokeScaleEnabled={false}
          points={flatten(obj.points)}
          closed
          draggable
          listening={listening}
          ref={shape}
          onClick={() => onClick(obj.id)}
          onDragStart={() => onDragStart(obj.id)}
          onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
        />
        <Transformer
          ref={transformer}
          rotateEnabled={false}
          ignoreStroke
          keepRatio={false}
          borderStroke={obj.color}
        />
      </>
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was using the incorrect transformer.  I adjusted it based on https://github.com/konvajs/konva/issues/1256.  I'm not sure what setting the scale to 1 does, specifically, but it was required to keep the object from jumping around unexpectedly.

```js
    const handleDragEnd = () => {
      const line = shape.current!;
      const transformer = line.getTransform();
      const next = sensor.roiPoints[0].map((coords) => {
        const { x, y } = transformer.point({
          x: coords[0],
          y: coords[1]
        });
        return [x, y];
      });

      line.points(flatten(next));
      line.scaleX(1);
      line.scaleY(1);
      line.x(0);
      line.y(0);
      onDragEnd(sensor.id, [next]);
    };
```