# keeping within bounds whene using Rotate Group Konvajs

Tags: javascript, geometry, rotation, konvajs, konva

I'm resizing an image and putting it in a group to crop it, and I'm limiting the image's drag.
It works very well when the group's rotation is 0.
However, when I rotate the group, the drag limit doesn't work as it should.
This may require some mathematical knowledge, and unfortunately, I'm not very skilled in that area.
Could you please help me limit the drag of the image when I rotate the group?
Here's the [demo](https://codepen.io/aymen2255/pen/WNLoXNq)

```js
let stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: "container",
  width: 800,
  height: 600
});
var layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

var background = new Konva.Rect({
  width: stage.width(),
  height: stage.height(),
  fill: "lightgray"
});
layer.add(background);

var blockPhoto = new Konva.Group({
  x: 200,
  y: 100,
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  draggable: true,
  rotation: 0,
  clip: {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 200,
    height: 200
  }
});
var rect = new Konva.Rect({
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  fill: "lightblue"
});

blockPhoto.add(rect);

var itemUrl =
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1683009686716-ac2096a5a73b?ixlib=rb-.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2070&q=80";
Konva.Image.fromURL(itemUrl, function (image) {
  resizeImgDimToOccupateAllGroup(blockPhoto, image);
  image.draggable(true);
  image.dragBoundFunc(function (pos) {
    var newX = pos.x;
    var newY = pos.y;
    var posRotatedGroup = getRectPosition(blockPhoto);
    if (newX + image.width() < posRotatedGroup.maxX) {
      newX = posRotatedGroup.maxX - image.width();
    }

    if (newX > posRotatedGroup.minX) {
      newX = posRotatedGroup.minX;
    }

    if (newY > posRotatedGroup.minY) {
      newY = posRotatedGroup.minY;
    }

    if (newY + image.height() < posRotatedGroup.maxY) {
      newY = posRotatedGroup.maxY - image.height();
    }
    return {
      x: newX,
      y: newY
    };
  });

  blockPhoto.add(image);
});

layer.add(blockPhoto);

function resizeImgDimToOccupateAllGroup(group, image) {
  var widthRatio = group.width() / image.width();
  var heightRatio = group.height() / image.height();

  var maxRatio = Math.max(widthRatio, heightRatio);

  var newImageWidth = image.width() * maxRatio;
  var newImageHeight = image.height() * maxRatio;

  image.width(newImageWidth);
  image.height(newImageHeight);
  return image;
}

function getRectPosition(rectangle) {
  const rectRotation = rectangle.rotation();
  const rectWidth = rectangle.width();
  const rectHeight = rectangle.height();
  const rectPosition = rectangle.getAbsolutePosition();

  // Convertir l'angle de rotation en radians
  const radians = (rectRotation * Math.PI) / 180;

  // Coordonnées des coins non tournés
  const x1 = rectPosition.x;
  const y1 = rectPosition.y;
  const x2 = x1 + rectWidth;
  const y2 = y1;
  const x3 = x1;
  const y3 = y1 + rectHeight;
  const x4 = x2;
  const y4 = y3;

  // Calcul des nouvelles coordonnées après rotation
  const rotatedX1 =
    rectPosition.x +
    (x1 - rectPosition.x) * Math.cos(radians) -
    (y1 - rectPosition.y) * Math.sin(radians);
  const rotatedY1 =
    rectPosition.y +
    (x1 - rectPosition.x) * Math.sin(radians) +
    (y1 - rectPosition.y) * Math.cos(radians);

  const rotatedX2 =
    rectPosition.x +
    (x2 - rectPosition.x) * Math.cos(radians) -
    (y2 - rectPosition.y) * Math.sin(radians);
  const rotatedY2 =
    rectPosition.y +
    (x2 - rectPosition.x) * Math.sin(radians) +
    (y2 - rectPosition.y) * Math.cos(radians);

  const rotatedX3 =
    rectPosition.x +
    (x3 - rectPosition.x) * Math.cos(radians) -
    (y3 - rectPosition.y) * Math.sin(radians);
  const rotatedY3 =
    rectPosition.y +
    (x3 - rectPosition.x) * Math.sin(radians) +
    (y3 - rectPosition.y) * Math.cos(radians);

  const rotatedX4 =
    rectPosition.x +
    (x4 - rectPosition.x) * Math.cos(radians) -
    (y4 - rectPosition.y) * Math.sin(radians);
  const rotatedY4 =
    rectPosition.y +
    (x4 - rectPosition.x) * Math.sin(radians) +
    (y4 - rectPosition.y) * Math.cos(radians);

  // Trouver les coordonnées minimales et maximales
  const minX = Math.min(rotatedX1, rotatedX2, rotatedX3, rotatedX4);
  const minY = Math.min(rotatedY1, rotatedY2, rotatedY3, rotatedY4);
  const maxX = Math.max(rotatedX1, rotatedX2, rotatedX3, rotatedX4);
  const maxY = Math.max(rotatedY1, rotatedY2, rotatedY3, rotatedY4);

  return {
    minX: minX,
    maxX: maxX,
    minY: minY,
    maxY: maxY
  };
}

const rotatePoint = ({ x, y }, rad) => {
  const rcos = Math.cos(rad);
  const rsin = Math.sin(rad);
  return { x: x * rcos - y * rsin, y: y * rcos + x * rsin };
};

// will work for shapes with top-left origin, like rectangle
function rotateAroundCenter(node, rotation) {
  //current rotation origin (0, 0) relative to desired origin - center (node.width()/2, node.height()/2)
  const topLeft = { x: -node.width() / 2, y: -node.height() / 2 };
  const current = rotatePoint(topLeft, Konva.getAngle(node.rotation()));
  const rotated = rotatePoint(topLeft, Konva.getAngle(rotation));
  const dx = rotated.x - current.x,
    dy = rotated.y - current.y;

  node.rotation(rotation);
  node.x(node.x() + dx);
  node.y(node.y() + dy);
}
$("#rotation").on("keyup", function () {
  var rotation = $("#rotation").val();
  rotateAroundCenter(blockPhoto, rotation);
});
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
Rotation: <input type="text" id="rotation" name="rotation" value="0">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@9.0.2/konva.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tackle this by looking at it as a question of whether the boundary rect is entirely within the image rect. If the image is being rotated, as in your case, it is easier to think of the image as a polygon. Now you can use a point-in-polygon check for each of the corner points of the boundary rect - if all those points are inside the polygon then accept the position, or if any will be outside the polygon then reject the move.

There is a good point-in-polygon algorithm and explanation [here](https://www.jeffreythompson.org/collision-detection/poly-point.php).

Note that this is a math-based solution and it will be very fast. Konva provides some collision checks but they will be slower because they require construction of an off-screen canvas and pixel matrix sampling to detect collision. Don't get me wrong, there are times when that slightly slower approach works well or is a life saver, but in your case you want to check the overlap of the rects during a drag and therefore performance is the focus.

Also note that this approach depends on your being able to get the corner points of the rotated image. There is an approach to that in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65645262/7073944).